# Get selected item from Angular List

Tags: html, angular

I have a list of elements displayed on my HTML page. For whatever element selected, I wish to retrieve the corresponding data from the firebase database.
Here's the code of how I am displaying the list on the HTML page. These items are retrieved from firebase.

```html
<div class="list-group " *ngFor="let year of years | async">

  <a routerLink="records" routerLinkActive="active">
    <mdb-icon fas icon="table" class="mr-3"></mdb-icon>{{year.key}}</a>

</div>
```

routerLink="records" , Records.html is where I would like to display the corresponding data.
Records is a html page where...based on the selected "year" , the data should be dynamically loaded.
[image: Items displayed on HTML page]
[image: Data in Firebase database]

Comment: can you clarify what  is the expected behavior ?!

Comment: @TawfiekKhalaf I have edited the question with more details . Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would use two services

one for your http calls (`apiService`) and one for storing the datas in your app (in that case `dataService`)

in your actual `ts`

```
years:any[] = []

//you can trigger that with ngOnInit or other events
this.apiService.getYears.subscribe(
  data => {
    this.dataService.setYears(data)
    this.years = this.dataService.getYears();
  }
)
```

in your html (no more `async` just data)

```
<div class="list-group " *ngFor="let year of years | async">
  <a [routerLink]="['records/'+ year.key]" routerLinkActive="active">
    <mdb-icon fas icon="table" class="mr-3"></mdb-icon>{{year.key}}</a>
</div>
```

then in your record component

```
year:any = undefined

//check for ActivatedRoute.params for retrieving the key (here `yearKey`) in your url

ngOnInit(){
  if (!(this.year = this.dataService.getYear(yearKey)))
    this.apiService.getYear(yearKey).subscribe(
      data => this.year = data
    )
}
```

**REFERENCES**

[Services](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4)

Comment: In your code, you are routing to year+"which ever year" html page...but I have only a single html page..where the data is dynamically loaded based on year.key

Comment: this is only one component but if you wan't to retrieve the a specific year you need to pass a year, year key or year id (call it how you want) you can pass them also as parameter `records?year=2015` but it still is the same

Comment: @AkhileshPothuri I've added a reply